# Sublime text 3: How to enable ctrl key bindings in Vintage mode?

Tags: sublimetext3

In Sublime text 3, there is according to the docs a setting to enable use of certain control key shortcuts that are disabled by default in Vintage mode. https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/vintage.html

I have put the line `"vintage_ctrl_keys": true` in my user preferences file, but the promised bindings

```
Ctrl+[: Escape
Ctrl+R: Redo
Ctrl+Y: Scroll down one line
Ctrl+E: Scroll up one line
Ctrl+F: Page Down
Ctrl+B: Page Up
```

don't work. Are there plugins that conflict with Vintage mode?

Answer (score 1):

There are indeed many plugins who use the Ctrl keys for shortcuts. To find them, you would have to look/search through each of your plugins' keybinding files to verify which conflicting bindings are preventing your setting from working.

You can do that with [this plugin](https://github.com/skuroda/PackageResourceViewer) and remove the key bindings you don't want. However, they'll probably reappear on the modified plugins' next update.

Alternatively, you can try overriding the original command by setting:

```
{ "keys": ["Ctrl+\["] }
```

and following that, setting the corresponding key binding from the Vintage package.